# Hunting rights to land but do not own the land

Tags: real-estate, ownership, alabama, easement

If a person inherits the hunting rights that are deeded and recorded, can the land owner force one to give the hunting rights back to him just because he wants to sell the land?

Comment: That depends on the jurisdiction.

Comment: The original sale that was recorded stated, " Sold to Ernest Waters for $1.00 and other valuable considerations, all the hunting rights on all my land." Signed Feb 7, 1987 with the parcel numbers recorded on the sheet as well. A lawyer did not draft the document. Both my father and the original owner of the land have passed away. Is it worth taking to court?

Comment: The current land owner wants me to relinquish all hunting rights over to him. He is wanting to sell the land but no one wants to purchase it without the hunting rights.

Comment: @Shelby: This is very location dependent. Can you tell us where the land is?

Comment: Conecuh County, AL

Comment: @Shelby: Can you [edit] the question to make it a general question in principle, rather than a specific question about *your* position please.  Otherwise it will be closed as "off topic" (requests for specific legal advice are off topic here).

Answer (score 2):

> If I inherited the hunting rights that was purchased by my father, deeded and >recorded, can the land owner make me give the hunting rights back to him just >because he wants to sell the land?

There is a legal term for the hunting rights your father purchased: "***personal easement in gross***".

Unfortunately, it appears that you probably did not actually inherit the rights because personal easements in gross (unlike commercial ones) [are not inheritable or transferrable](http://www.caddenfuller.com/Articles/Real-Estate-Law-Easement-Basics.shtml):

> Because noncommercial easements in gross are treated as a right of
>   personal enjoyment for the original holder, they are generally not
>   transferable. Recreational rights such as hunting, camping and fishing
>   are the most common examples of nontransferable,
>   noncommercial-easements in gross.

[To be clear](https://www.realestatelawyers.com/legal-advice/real-estate/land-use-zoning/can-easement-gross-inherited-sold-ohio):

> Usually, a personal easement in gross terminates on the death of the
>   easement owner.

Therefore, unless Alabama has a law that explicitly makes personal easements in gross inheritable/transferrable (which, upon quick search, does not appear to be the case, but you really should talk to a lawyer to find out for sure), you actually do not have any hunting rights on the land.

Because the owner of the land thinks that you still have the rights, you have two options:

- Try to convince him (e.g. tell him to talk to a lawyer) that you do
  not have the hunting rights, so there is nothing for him to worry
  about; OR
- If he still wants you to explicitly relinquish any hunting rights in the unlikely case you have them, you can do so for a consideration (e.g. $1 or whatever you agree on). This would be a contract between you and him that will give him (and his prospective buyers) a peace of mind.

Comment: What makes this sale of the hunting rights an easement verses a profits à prendre, which is transferable?

Comment: @Shelby Good question. It looks like _profit-à-prendre_ and _easement_ are different things in Europe, but the same in the US (where _easement_ is used for harvesting/hunting rights too and not just for right of way).

Comment: In Colorado, a personal easement in gross is assignable absent expressly language in the easement to the contrary. This is the modern rule.